# Reuse function to load data into Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a Highchart object and a function to load the data:

```
graficaPropuestas = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            height: 300,
            renderTo: "graficaPropuestas",
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            events: {
                load: recogerDatosInforme('propuesta', $(this))
            }
        }
 })
```

And the function to load the data:

```
function recogerDatosInforme(tipo, gr) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Licencia/recogerDatosUsuariosSistema?tipo' + tipo,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                gr.series[0].setData(data);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
```

I want to pass the graficaPropuestas object to the function so I can reuse the same function to load more graphs, however I cant get this to work. If I put in the function directly the graficaPropuestas object on the success: method it work well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand how you would like to use `graficaPropuestas` object in success function?

Comment: Hi! I would like to use the graficaPropuestas object because I have more charts object on the code, so I would like to have only one function to fetch the data from the server. The question is if this is the correct way to pass an object to a function.

Comment: I suppose you pass `graficaPropuestas ` in `gr` parameter?

Comment: Yes... Is it supposed to be the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

If you will have only one instance of `graficaPropuestas` better and more efficient will be to use that solution:

```
var graficaPropuestas = new Highcharts.Chart( ... 

function recogerDatosInforme(tipo) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Licencia/recogerDatosUsuariosSistema?tipo' + tipo,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                graficaPropuestas.series[0].setData(data);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by this way:

The function to get the data:

```
function recogerDatosInforme(tipo, gr) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Informes/recogerDatosInforme?tipo=' + tipo,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                gr.series[0].setData(data);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
```

Then I create the chart whithout the events method on the init:

```
graficaPropuestas = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        height: 300,
        renderTo: "graficaPropuestas",
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    }
```

})

And the I call the function with the graph object as an argument:

```
recogerDatosInforme('propuesta', graficaPropuestas)
```

So now I can make more chart objects and use the same function to get the data.